# Extract Rules from InfoPath Form

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

Is there a way to automatically grab the rules, in their original, human readable format from an InfoPath 2007 form (probably the manifest.xsf file, they're not human readable here)?  A commercial tool would be fine, even.  We're looking to build a summary of the rules as they appear in the design form for easy browsing by a maintenance team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the Logic Instpector built in to InfoPath that displays a page that lists all the rules, data validation, calculated default values, etc. It can be found under Tools -> Logic Inspector.  Unfortunalty, other than pressing the Print button in the top left corner and printing to PDF I see no other way of exporting this information from within infopath.

To get the same sort of info collected into a report format I susspect that you will have to extract the files from the XSN and extract the default values, rules etc.

As for commertial tool a possibility is the [qDabra Rules](http://www.qdabra.com/en/products/qRules.aspx).
I have not used it at all and am not sure if it does export the rules to a human readable format but it should point you in the right direction (I hope)

Comment: The rules are in the manifest but they've been converted to XPath queries.  I'll check out qDabra, thank you.